# â‚¬ is coming instead of regular Euro sign in ISO-8859-1 in Magento

Tags: magento, utf-8, character-encoding, multilingual

â‚¬ is displayed instead of Euro sign in ISO-8859-1

I am using this character set for my French, Spanish, German and Italian stores.

Please tell me how to fix this euro sign problem or any other solution to display special characters of above listed languages.

Comment: It had been proposed to put the Euro Sign in place of the plus-minus sign instead of the currency sign. There was strong opposition on this. "The proposed «+-» is not an adequate fall-back, as this sequence, though rarely used, has a fixed mathematical meaning, quite different from «±»; if a reader would deduce the intended meaning, «±», from the context, «+-» in lieu of «±» will hurt a physicist's æsthetic feelings at least as much as «oe» in lieu of an o-e ligature a Francophone's. As a result of the opposition, ISO 8859-15 kept the plus-minus sign and removed the currency sign instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done like,

```
     <?php echo mb_convert_encoding($this->__('Careers'), "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); ?>
```

and keep charset default UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

There is no euro sign character in ISO 8859-1; it was introduced in ISO 8859-15 and it is present in UTF-8, however it seems you just need to use `&euro;` html entity.

Comment: where are you setting the encoding (http response or html head)? where is the character stored (from database, in a file). Because of the garbage that is showing is 2 byte long, it seems the character is store in some UTF-8 place and you are trying to show it in a ISO8859 page.

Comment: i have written this code in head.phtml <?php Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",false); ?>

Comment: can't you just use `&euro;`?

Comment: where should i put this? I mean this currency is only for my 4 stores. in one store i have pound currency

Comment: Instead of the euro character. It is called html entity, like `&agrave;` for à, `&amp;` for & and so on. http://htmlentities.net/html/entities/

Comment: I get your point. But i m using $this->helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false) in my phtml file
so I have confusio regarding in which file I use this?

Comment: i have same problem on list & product details page how to do exact?

Answer (score 6):

Magento uses UTF-8 everywhere: Templates, database, translation files. If you send a `content-type` header for ISO-8859-1, all data is still UTF-8 encoded but will be displayed incorrect (that's what you see, a UTF-8 euro sign, interpreted as ISO-8859-1).

There is no reason to prefer ISO-8859-1 over UTF-8. If you add own files or data which is in ISO-8859-1, convert them first.

Comment: how to accomplish? please help. I need some steps like solution. so it would be helpful if u provide me that

Comment: change the encoding from ISO-8859-1 in the Html head to UTF-8.