# Webkit suddenly starts serving scripts with different encoding?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, webkit

So last week, one of our applications started to display a weird bug: the `€` signs got displayed as `â‚¬` signs. After some digging around, I noticed that it happened to every price amount we display that went through a formatting function. So checking the source code in devtools revealed why we were seeing a different character:

```
  return "â‚¬ " + x1 + ",-"
```

So, it looks like the script got served with a different encoding than UTF-8. The source code clearly shows a euro sign on that line, but the source tab in Chrome devtools says different.

I tested it out in multiple browsers where Firefox, IE 11 and Edge correctly showed a euro sign. Opera didn't, so that looks like it's a Webkit issue?

If I full-refresh the page in Chrome (ctrl+shift+R), everything looks okay and all euro signs are rendered correctly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040294/%C3%A2-%C2%AC-is-coming-instead-of-regular-euro-sign-in-iso-8859-1-in-magento) states that the `â‚¬` character is displayed because ISO-8859-1 is used for rendering (which doesn't have the euro sign). Is it possible for Webkit to just pick a different encoding to parse JavaScript files with than UTF-8?

Comment: No, You missed the meaning: `â‚¬` is the UTF-8 encoding of eurosign, if you read it as Latin1 (so byte per byte). So it seems that encoding is correct, but web server or html page tell the browser that encoding is latin1. Check the response headers of HTTP request and the HEAD of HTML file.

Comment: Your comment pointed me into the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Giacomo Catenazzi's comment above pointed me into the right direction. The application is hosted on a Java back-end, and as such has a `login.html` and `app.html` page that the Java back-end serves as `index`. I knew that `app.html` has a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in the `<head>`, but the comment inspired me to check `login.html` and I noticed that it **missed the meta tag**.

`login.html` loads the application script file. So when the user logs in, Chrome fetches the script file on the login page with no specific encoding, and when the user moves on to the application page, the (improper encoded) script file is served from cache. This explains why a refresh fixed everything (scripts get refetched from server), and it also explains why this happened "suddenly". The login page was changed recently to load the scripts file.

TLDR; make sure every HTML file that fetches scripts has a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in its `<head>`.

Comment: Nice troubleshooting. Alternatively or in addition, convert HTML4 files to HTML5, as indicated by their doctypte declarations.